# Xpath to strip text using substring-after

Tags: xpath

I have the following which is the **second** span in html with the class of 'ProductListOurRef':

```
<span class="ProductListOurRef">Product Code: 60076</span>
```

Ive tried the following Xpath:

```
(//span[@class="ProductListOurRef"])[2]
```

But that returns `'Product Code: 60076'`. But I need to use Xpath to strip the `'Product Code: '` to just give me the result of `'60076'`.

I believe `'substring-after'` should do it but i dont know how to write it

Comment: `substring-after((//span[@class="ProductListOurRef"])[2], ': ')`

Comment: That gives 'Invalid Custom Extraction Configured'

Comment: From what XPath library or application?

Comment: its an application called Screamingfrog

Comment: The problem lies with Screaminfrog, not @JLRishe's XPath.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XPath 1.0, then the result of an XPath expression must be either a node-set, a single string, a single number, or a single boolean.

As shown in comments on the question, you can write a query using `substring-after()`, whose result is a string.

However, some applications expect the result of an XPath expression always to be a node-set, and it looks as if you are stuck with such an application. Because you can't construct new nodes in XPath (you can only select nodes that are already present in the input), there is no way around this.